# Pick up [phrasal verb] with pronouns

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice, phrasal-verbs

> The baby has dropped its toy, I'll .............

Options are:

1. pick up it.
2. pick it up

In this question I know the answer would be No. 2 — pick it up.

I just need any source, grammar book or dictionary, that affirms not to use the pronoun *it* after the phrasal verb *pick up* such as in the first answer.

In other words, a rule that prevent using the pronoun after the phrasal verb *pick up*.

Comment: Please don't call it a 'phrasal verb'; there's really no such thing! "Pick" is here a 'prepositional verb' because it selects the preposition "up" as its complement. The order 'particle + object' is inadmissible if the object has the form of an unstressed personal pronoun, as it does in "pick up it". Compare "pick Ed up" ~ "pick up Ed".

Comment: You'll find optionally separable (not for many pronoun objects/complements, as @BillJ says) (_she turned on the light / turned the light / it on_), mandatorily separable (_his coach got him / John through the hard times_, and non-separable (_they look after their mother_) transitive multi-word verbs (I'm using Claudia Claridge's nomenclature) attributed as such in the 'Oxford Phrasal Verbs Dictionary' (they still use ill-defined terminology).

Comment: ["If the object is a personal pronoun (me, you, him, us, etc.), we always put the pronoun before the particle..."](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/phrasal-verbs-and-multi-word-verbs)

Comment: It's all right to call it a 'phrasal verb'; most linguists would say that _pick up_ in that sense was precisely a [phrasal verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/96943/15299), because it requires [Particle Shift](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+particle+shift) with pronoun objects. That's the basic test for transitive phrasal verbs. Some have different ideas, but we don't try to correct people by decree here.

Comment: @JohnLawler The term 'phrasal verb' is misleading since it implies that "pick up" is a verb, a constituent, at word level, which it isn't. It's not the whole expression "pick up" which is a verb; it's just the lexeme "pick".

Comment: @Billj  It doesn't matter whether it's misleading; it's the term we've got for a specific and well-known phenomenon. Nobody cares what it might imply, in the theory you favor; after all, everybody's got their own theory. Gods know that "future tense", for instance, has not yet disappeared, despite the fact that it implies that there is a future tense in English, which is false.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't use the the term 'phenomenon' in connection with 'phrasal verb' since the terms 'phrasal verb' and 'particle' relate to two distinct and concepts. And yes, it _does_ matter because students see the term 'phrasal verb' and assume it's a single constituent, some kind of compound verb, which it isn't. If I had a quid for every time I've had to correct a student on this point I'd be a rich man!

Comment: @BillJ You don't *need* to correct students, at least not if your intention is to help them learn. I've never met a student whose learning was harmed because of the technical inaccuracy of the term "phrasal verb". They all know that the term refers to that type of verb. It could reasonably harm a student to tell them that "pick up" is not a phrasal verb when all the resources they're given say it is, and none of their resources mention "prepositional verbs".

Comment: Arguing over whether a group of words like "pick up" should be called a "phrasal verb" or not is not helpful to learners, which is the audience now that this is on ELL. It is a fact that such word groups act in many ways like verbs. It is a fact that many ESL resources, both texts and online, use the term "phrasal verb" for this sort of thing, even if some theories of grammar say that is an incorrect term. Please let us concentrate on answering the question (and others here on ELL) not on debating terminology.

Answer (score 2):

You find this rule in the OALD, paper edition from 2005.

> When the object is a pronoun (for example **it** standing for 'the letter' in "She tore the letter up."), it must always go between the verb and the particle:
>
> - She read the letter and she tore it up.

OALD: *Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary of Current English*, A S Hornby